# run \dt in oracle sqldeveloper for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I configured PostgreSQL for Oracle SQL developer.

I just tried to run the command `\dt;` from the worksheet and received below error

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
\dt 
Error report -
SQL Error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
  Position: 1
```

Could you please advise how to run the commonly used psql commands from worksheet in Oracle SQL developer.
Edit1:
Are there any alternative equivalent for such psql command for oracle sql developer please. Thanks.

Comment: `\dt` is a **`psql`** meta-command. It's not a SQL command, so it can only be used from within `psql`

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't SQL Developer offer a GUI view that provides the same info as \dt does?  That is its job, afterall, and the point of using a GUI.

You can start `psql` with the `-E` option, then it will show you the SQL it executes to get the data behind the various backslash commands.  You can then capture and run those queries in something else, like (presumably, I haven't tried it) SQL Developer.

Comment: thank you for your inputs. I was looking for quick query.I will explore the psql -E option thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.

`psql` commands are only available in `psql`.

Consider using `psql`, it is superior.

Comment: thank you. The reason I am switching to oracle sql developer is on the command line in linux the data gets garbled. Also oracle sql developer gives me quick gui view which I am more comfortable with. Any way to make life easier on command line using psql please, thanks.

Comment: It is of course a matter of taste, but (different from sqlplus) `psql` doesn't garble the output. I cannot argue with the "quick overview", but I get along well with `\dn`, `\dt`, `\df` and friends.

Comment: when I say garble, I mean hard to read for me, if there are too many columns in the table. THanks

Comment: Oh, I see. If you are on an operating system different from Windows, set the environment variable `PAGER` to `less -RS`, then you can scroll left and right.

Comment: I am getting below error, could you please advise, thank you.                                   mm_db1-# PAGER='less -RS'
mm_db1-# select * from table1 ;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PAGER"
LINE 1: PAGER='less -RS'

Comment: I am using linux terminal and all data is not coming on one line

Comment: I was talking about an *environment variable*. From `psql` you could use `\setenv` to set it.

Comment: I tried that but some how it is not working. thanks.